# call function inside $ (function () {...}) jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, call

call function inside `$ (function () {...})`

example:

```
$ (function () {
     makeAlert function (text) {
         alert (text) 
     } 
});
```

I want to call "makeAlert" function from any  block.

makeAlert simply `call ()` does not work.

please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You've scoped the function to the function it is declared within.

Move it outside so that it is a global. There is no need to delay its definition until the ready event fires.

---

Alternatively, create a global reference to it within the outer function.

```
window.makeAlert = makeAlert;
```

It wouldn't recommend this unless you have some other good reason to keep the function from being declared until the ready event fires as it is more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Functions defined with `function XYZ()` are scoped to the function block they are in.

They can be made global with `window.XYZ = function() {...}`. The same applies to variables.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window = $(function () {
            makeAlert = function (text) {
                     alert (text); 
                    } 
            return {
                makeAlert: makeAlert                  
            }

        }(jQuery))[0]; 
</script>
```

then call makeAlert("hello");